# next/image loads very big images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Next js in my project and using next/image for loading images. My page is roughly `1600px` wide and has 3 thumbnails per row which are of `500px` in width as seen below.
[image]

So I needed `next/image` to load 500px width versions of the thumbnails but it loads the image with `1600px` width.

here's the component I've used

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image
  src={article.thumbnail}
  width={500}
  height={277}
  layout="responsive"
/>
```

my next.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
    deviceSizes: [320, 640, 660, 768, 1024, 1600],
    loader: 'cloudinary',
    path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/',
  }
};
```

the output that next gives on HTML looks as follows:

```html
<div style="display:block;overflow:hidden;position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0">
   <div style="display:block;box-sizing:border-box;padding-top:55.400000000000006%"></div>
   <img 
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_1600,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png" 
    decoding="async" 
    style="visibility: inherit; position: absolute; inset: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%;" 
    sizes="100vw" 
    srcset="
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_320,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 320w,
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_640,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 640w,
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_660,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 660w,
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_768,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 768w,
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_1024,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 1024w,
      https://res.cloudinary.com/pratiek/f_auto,c_limit,w_1600,q_auto/strapi_7efe62d320.png 1600w"
    />
</div>
```

I think the last line is what is wrong with the output, it is calling for 1600px image on 1600px viewport, but I need 500px image on 1600px viewport, how do I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should add `sizes={"30vw"}` prop to your images to get what you want.
According to [nextjs doc on sizes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#sizes) default is 100vw and when you use `layout="responsive` nextjs loads the image to fit the entire screen.

With `sizes={"30vw"}` you are saying this image will be one third of the entire viewport and you'll probably get 640px wide image since that's the closest larger breakpoint in your `deviceSizes: [320, 640, 660, 768, 1024, 1600]`. (1600px / 3 = ~530px)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening due to

```js
layout="responsive
```

As per `next`'s documentation:

**layout**

When **fixed**, the image dimensions will not change as the viewport changes (no responsiveness) similar to the native img element.

When **intrinsic**, the image will scale the dimensions down for smaller viewports but maintain the original dimensions for larger viewports.

When **responsive**, the image will scale the dimensions down for smaller viewports and scale up for larger viewports.

When **fill**, the image will stretch both width and height to the dimensions of the parent element, usually paired with the objectFit property.

Find out more here:- [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout)

Comment: I do want it responsive though, as I want it to load lower resolution images for smaller viewports.

Comment: Then you can try to add stylings (dimensions) to its parent `<div>`. This will restrict the image from growing. Make sure you only add width, so that the image is not stretched.